# Why does IKManager.getArmatureByName("ArmaturenName") return a null object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I wrote this simple code to work on some Inverse Kinematics using ActionScript 3.0, trying to mimic Adobe's AS3 (not so lucid) [**example**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS76E4A0A2-F3D9-43c8-BA07-A2B6D6DE5266.html) on the same topic. However the **IKManager** cannot find the perfectly valid Armature Object that I've created. can anyone explain this odd behavior?

Here's a snapshot of my code - https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bz-7s0GCEAA4qFH.jpg:large

Comment: You can upload your picture using stackoverflow's built-in system, that way it will be here even if your original host goes down.

Comment: Consider using [`IKManager.numArmatures`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/ik/IKManager.html#numArmatures) to see if it has even detected your armature.